# Compare substrig with split in java

Tags: java

I have `'R-121|123|123'` this type of string.

Now I want to split the above string in two sub string.
For example : `Two sub string after splitting R and 121|123|123`
I can split easily by using '`-`' this operator.

We can also do the same thing by using substring operator.

Which one is better (split or substring) ?

Comment: if its easy as you describe in your question `split` its fine but i prefer `Pattern` and `Matcher` Class

Answer (score 1):

Split goes through your entire string, and creates new objects plus the array object itself,

So substring would definitely be more efficient

this may be useful :

http://www.gettingcirrius.com/2010/11/performance-comparison-string-split-vs.html

Comment: That link does not provide a fair comparison. The substring version doesn't have to search for the position to split on, so of course it is way faster. Nothing in this question says that the `-` is in a well-known position, so you'd have to do an `indexOf()` before `substring()`.

Comment: I know , but i answer it in general

Answer (score 0):

Split is more clean way. If data set is small split can be used.
Regarding performance i am not very clear how substring will be better than split.
I have also read that substring is better but i am not convinced because in case of substring also string traversal is required to find index. so traversing time should be same.
 But yes split will create all new objects based on delimiter, which will be garbage collected. 
So as per my understanding, if requirement is to get all the tokens then use split but if  specific occurrence is needed then better to go for substring.

Comment: Traversal time would not be the same. `split(String)` uses a regular expression, while a `substring()` implementation would use `indexOf(char)`.

Comment: @Andreas Right split uses regex, but in some cases as mentioned below
if the regex is a
         (1)one-char String and this character is not one of the
            RegEx's meta characters ".$|()[{^?*+\\", or
         (2)two-char String and the first char is the backslash and
            the second is not the ascii digit or ascii letter.
split and substring both will be using indexOf.